# Specifying non-standard baud rate for FTDI virtual serial port under Linux

Tags: linux, serial-port, virtual-serial-port

I have a USB device I'm trying to communicate with over a virtual serial port provided by the ftdi_sio kernel module. However, I'm having some trouble setting the baud rate of the port to 14400:

- `termios.h` doesn't specify a constant for 14400, so I can't use `cfsetispeed` and `cfsetospeed`.
- In the source for the ftdi_sio kernel module, baud base is set to 24000000 and there doesn't seem to be a way to change it. This means I can't use a custom divisor with the `TIOCSSERIAL` ioctl and get a 14400 baud rate that way.
- The module source has a comment making it sound like setting the `alt_speed` member of the `tty_struct` structure for the port to 14400 would do what I want, but there doesn't seem to be any way to set it to 14400 given the existing interfaces.

Does anyone have any ideas about this? It'd be pretty easy to fix this by hacking up the kernel module, but I'm really looking for a solution that doesn't require kernel changes.

Comment: ISTR that back in the days when Dave Grohl was the drummer for Nirvana, 14400 baud modems were used with a port speed of 19200 baud - does your device not work at 19200?

Comment: No, unfortunately, it's 14400 or bust.

Comment: It is a very common thing that baudrate resulting from baudbase / divisor is not the exact baudrate. This usually is not a problem.

You won't get exact baudrate if your serial hardware crystal can't provide it. especially with ftdi like hardware, I doubt you can change the baud base.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't change baud base, I suppose it is hardware related. So messing with the module won't do you any good. In your third point you only talk about the first method proposed for setting a custom baudrate, where you need to access the `tty->alt_speed`. It seems there is no interface to directly set tty struct from userspace, at least not with the ftdi_sio driver.
However, there is another method explained in the comments :

```
     * 3. You can also set baud rate by setting custom divisor as follows
     *    - set tty->termios->c_cflag speed to B38400
     *    - call TIOCSSERIAL ioctl with (struct serial_struct) set as
     *      follows:
     *      o flags & ASYNC_SPD_MASK == ASYNC_SPD_CUST
     *      o custom_divisor set to baud_base / your_new_baudrate
```

Did you try it ?

Comment: I've tried this, but custom_divisor is an integral type, so while I can get 14405 or 14397, 14400 is out of the question.

Baud base twiddling looked useful to me as it only appears to be used to derive the actual baud rate used in the third case that you mention. However, I've just noticed the comments relating to `FTDI_SIO_SET_BAUDRATE` in ftdi_sio.h - I'll have to check if I can use that to twiddle the divisor in a useful way.

Comment: A-ha! As per your comment above (not going for exactly 14.4k), I ended having a closer look at the `get_ftdi_divisor` function - using a divisor of 1666 (i.e., 14405 baud) does the trick, as that leads to the same value being sent to the device in the USB control message that sets the actual serial baud rate as would be sent for 14400. Thanks a million!

Comment: Those rates are both well within any reasonable error of margin and should work. It's very hard for the other device to generate a baud rate that is precise enough for it to detect a failure when talking to another device at 14,405 or 13,397. The error is so small.

Answer (score 3):

Shodanex's solution works with an NDI Polaris Spectra (baud 1.2mbps) under Linux.  As specified, open the serial device (/dev/ttyUSB0) with B38400,

```
int port = open("/dev/ttyUSB0", O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_NONBLOCK);
tcgetattr(port,&g_initialAtt);// save this to restore later
newAtt=g_initialAtt;
newAtt.c_cflag = B38400 | CS8 | CLOCAL | CREAD; 
cfmakeraw(&newAtt);
tcsetattr(port,TCSANOW,&newAtt);
```

then execute:

```
if(ioctl(port, TIOCGSERIAL, &sstruct) < 0){
    printf("Error: could not get comm ioctl\n"); 
    exit(0); 
}
sstruct.custom_divisor = custDiv;
//sstruct.flags &= 0xffff ^ ASYNC_SPD_MASK; NO! makes read fail.
sstruct.flags |= ASYNC_SPD_CUST; 
if(ioctl(port, TIOCSSERIAL, &sstruct) < 0){
    printf("Error: could not set custom comm baud divisor\n"); 
    exit(0); 
}
```

Comment: Also have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4968529/how-to-set-baud-rate-to-307200-on-linux/7152671#7152671