# Using tcdrain along with termios2

Tags: serial-port, termios

I want to use `tcdrain` with termios2.

The problem is the method is defined in `termios.h`, but not in `asm/termbits.h`.

It is [not possible](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19992472/962941) to use `termios.h` with `asm/termbits.h` together as there would have compilation errors as some of the structs are defined in both files.

**Background:** I would like to control my serial transmission by invoking `tcdrain` after `write` to make sure my data have transmitted before continue execution of my program. I would like also use custom serial speeds (thus, using `termios2`).

How do I use tcdrain with termios2?

Answer (score 0):

tcdrain is a simple ioctl call:

```
ioctl (fd, TCSBRK, 1)
```