# APQ-8016 Snapdragon 410c: non-standard UART baudrate in Linaro

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, serial-port, linux-device-driver, uart

Is the Snapdragon 410c ttyMSM1 (msm_serial) running Linux (linaro) capable of natively providing the DMX protocol 250,000 baudrate?

```
    root@linaro-developer:~# stty -F /dev/ttyMSM1 cs8 -parenb cstopb 250000

stty: invalid argument ‘250000’ 

Try 'stty --help' for more information.
```

250000 is not in the list of supported baudrates in the kernel/drivers/tty/tty_ioctl.c:baud_table[], and the setserial custom 38400 baudrate commands do not override the baudrate correctly.

```
root@linaro-developer:~# setserial -av /dev/ttyMSM1 spd_cust
[  491.312449] msm_serial 78af000.serial: setserial sets custom speed on ttyMSM1. This is deprecated.
```

Cross-posted here (I will keep both boards in sync as I work towards an answer): 
http://www.96boards.org/forums/topic/linaro-ttymsm1-uart0-dmx-250000-baudrate/#post-17264

Comment: You have to use an application that supports `BOTHER`. AFAIK *picocom* can be compiled with such support. Didn't try though.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem and wasn't able to find correct tool for my case, so I decided it's faster to come up with my own code. Next code uses `termios2` API (and `BOTHER` flag, that Andy Shevchenko mentioned in his comment) for setting custom baud rate for serial port.

Never looked in your serial driver code, but you can try this code first:

**main.c**:

```c
#include "termios2.h"

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    struct termios2 tio;
    int fd, ret, speed;

    if (argc != 3) {
        printf("%s device speed\n\n"
                "Set speed for a serial device.\n"
                "For instance:\n    %s /dev/ttyUSB0 75000\n",
                argv[0], argv[0]);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    fd = open(argv[1], O_RDONLY);
    if (fd == -1) {
        perror("open() error");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    speed = atoi(argv[2]);

    ret = ioctl(fd, TCGETS2, &tio);
    if (ret == -1) {
        perror("TCFETS2 error");
        close(fd);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    /* Speed settings */
    tio.c_cflag &= ~CBAUD;
    tio.c_cflag |= BOTHER;
    tio.c_ispeed = speed;
    tio.c_ospeed = speed;

    /* Ignore CR (\r) characters */
    tio.c_iflag |= IGNCR;

    ret = ioctl(fd, TCSETS2, &tio);
    if (ret == -1) {
        perror("TCSETS2 error");
        close(fd);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    close(fd);
    return 0;
}
```

**termios2.h**:

```c
/* The content for this file was borrowed from:
 * /usr/include/asm-generic/termbits.h
 *
 * We can't just include <asm/termios.h>, because it will interfere with
 * regular <termios.h> (compiler will give some errors).
 * So it's better to copy needed stuff here instead.
 */

#ifndef TERMIOS2_H
#define TERMIOS2_H

#include <termios.h>

/* termios.h defines NCCS as 32, but for termios2 we need it to be 19 */
#undef NCCS
#define NCCS        19

#define BOTHER      0010000

struct termios2 {
    tcflag_t c_iflag;       /* input mode flags */
    tcflag_t c_oflag;       /* output mode flags */
    tcflag_t c_cflag;       /* control mode flags */
    tcflag_t c_lflag;       /* local mode flags */
    cc_t c_line;            /* line discipline */
    cc_t c_cc[NCCS];        /* control characters */
    speed_t c_ispeed;       /* input speed */
    speed_t c_ospeed;       /* output speed */
};

#endif /* TERMIOS2_H */
```

Build:

```
$ gcc -Wall -O2 main.c -o set-tty-speed
```

Usage:

```
$ ./set-tty-speed /dev/ttyMSM1 250000
```

Also see this question: [How to set a custom baud rate on Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12646324/how-to-set-a-custom-baud-rate-on-linux)

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I had seen this post and had struggled with the compiler errors.  AFAICT this is not working on the snapdragon. I am concerned that the 250000 baudrate is not supported by the hardware, or at least requires a tweaking of the system clocks.  I am going to dive into the driver later this week and will update the question at that time.

Comment: The trick is to describe `termios2` manually, rather than include `asm/termios.h`. Try to use the code I provided. It builds like a charm for me. Other than that, if the problem is actually in the driver (`msm_serial`), then this code alone won't help you, of course. But I can confirm it works for my PL2303. So at least you can use it to verify that the actual issue is in your driver.