# Trying to write AT commands to USB to OBDii cable that uses FT232R to read ECU data (ISO 9141-2)

Tags: c, serial-port, usb, at-command, obd-ii

I am trying to read data from an ECU using the ISO 9141-2 protocol. The cable I'm using is OBD2 to USB, using a FT232R chip.
The programs that I am running are in C.

When I write commands to the serial port (ttyUSB0) it writes to it fine but when it reads back the received data it just returns the same data. Instead of returning the data from the ECU, I'm not sure on why it is doing this.

Any help is great, thanks.

Example code - Tried with setting the baud rate etc but no luck either.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
    char *port = "/dev/ttyUSB0";
    char receivedData[100];

    int n, fd; 

    fd = open(port, O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY);

    if(fd > 0){
        n = write(fd, "AT I\r\n", 10);
        read(fd, receivedData, 10);
        printf("%s\n", receivedData);

        close(fd);
    }
    else{
        printf("failed to open device\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Perhaps because you use the same buffer to read and write and read fails and that's why it appears to be the same. Please share the code, otherwise we can only guess.

Comment: Added code to original question. As I'm trying to read data from an ECU I wasn't sure if authentication would be needed also?

Comment: `write(fd, "AT I\r\n", 10)` is undefined behaviour, you are overflowing the string literal and you may be sending garbage to the device. `write(fd, "AT I\r\n", strlen("AT I\r\n"))` is correct

Comment: After changing that the I just receive the same data back. So I send "AT I\r\n" and receive "AT I" instead of actual data from the ECU. I'm struggling to figure out why it just returns the same thing.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the ISO 9141-2 protocol, check the manual, perhaps you need to send another AT command before `AT I` in order to enable access to it.

Comment: Although when I send the command "AT 0105\r\n" to get the coolant temp (may be wrong) I receive ��� from the ECU for some reason

Comment: Thank you, I will try to see what I can find. I wasn't aware that there could be some commands before to enable it

Comment: A quick google search of this protocol showed me many pages but they all use CAN, not AT command. Are you sure that this chip of yours understands AT command?

Comment: The ECU that I am connecting to use the pins for the ISO-9141-2 protocol and not CAN

Comment: Do you have a link to the documentation? All I found are reference of the protocol using CAN.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure but I believe it is AT commands that are sent to the device. Nothing I have read says anything about using CAN, as that is a different protocol

Comment: I know that CAN is a different protocol, I've worked with it for many years. Like I said is that I did a quick google search on ISO 9141-2 and all I got was pages that said it uses CAN, no mention of AT commands. That's why I asked if you have a link to the manual to take a look into it.

Comment: You need to initialize the tty. At least turn off echo and set a correct baud rate.

Comment: Ah sorry misinterpreted, I'm new to this sort of thing with these protocols. All I know is the ECU that is connected is using ISO-9141-2 protocol, and I have a USB to OBDii cable that i believe has a FT232R chip

Comment: How would I initialize the tty? and I have tried setting  the baud rate but I think i've got the wrong speed

Answer (score 1):

Even though this is not a direct answer to the question, this amount of code
does not fit in the comment section.

I use these functions to initialize the serial lines:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <termios.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>


struct baud_map {
    int baud;
    speed_t speed;
};

struct baud_map baudmap[] = {
    { 50        , B50 },
    { 75        , B75 },
    { 110       , B110 },
    { 134       , B134 },
    { 150       , B150 },
    { 200       , B200 },
    { 300       , B300 },
    { 600       , B600 },
    { 1200      , B1200 },
    { 1800      , B1800 },
    { 2400      , B2400 },
    { 4800      , B4800 },
    { 9600      , B9600 },
    { 19200     , B19200 },
    { 38400     , B38400 },
    { 57600     , B57600 },
    { 115200    , B115200 },
    { 230400    , B230400 },
    { 0,      0 }
};

int dbits_map[] = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, CS5, CS6, CS7, CS8 };

enum parity_t {
    PARITY_NO_PARITY,
    PARITY_ODD,
    PARITY_EVEN
};

int baud_to_speed(int baud, speed_t *speed)
{
    if(speed == NULL)
        return 0;

    struct baud_map *map = baudmap;
    while(map->baud)
    {
        if(map->baud == baud)
        {
            *speed = map->speed;
            return 1;
        }

        map++;
    }

    return 0;
}

/*
 * tty: "/dev/ttyUSB0"
 * baud: baudrate, for example 9600
 * parity: see enum parity_t
 * stop_bits: 1 or 2
 * data_bits: [5-8]
 *
 * return the fd on success, -1 on failure
 */
int openSerial_long(const char *tty, int baud, enum parity_t parity, int stop_bits, int data_bits)
{
    int fd;

    speed_t speed;

    if(baud_to_speed(baud, &speed) == 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Invalid baudrate %d\n", baud);
        return 0;
    }

    fd = open(tty, O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY  | O_NONBLOCK);

    if(fd == -1)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not open %s as a tty: %s\n", tty, strerror(errno));
        return -1;
    }

    struct termios termios;

    if(tcgetattr(fd, &termios) == -1)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not get tty attributes from %s: %s\n", tty, strerror(errno));
        close(fd);
        return -1;
    }

    // setting common values
    termios.c_iflag &= ~ICRNL;           // do not translate \r into \n
    termios.c_oflag &= ~OPOST;           // do not map \n to \r\n
    termios.c_cflag |= (CREAD | CLOCAL); // enable receiver & ignore model ctrl lines
    termios.c_lflag |= (ISIG | ICANON);  // enable signals and noncanonical mode
    termios.c_lflag &= ~ECHO;             // disable echo


    cfsetispeed(&termios, speed);
    cfsetospeed(&termios, speed);

    switch(parity)
    {
        case PARITY_NO_PARITY:
            termios.c_cflag &= ~PARENB;
            break;
        case PARITY_ODD:
            termios.c_cflag |= PARENB;
            termios.c_cflag |= PARODD;
            break;
        case PARITY_EVEN:
            termios.c_cflag |= PARENB;
            termios.c_cflag &= ~PARODD;
            break;
        default:
            fprintf(stderr, "invalid parity\n");
            break;
    }

    if(stop_bits == 1)
        termios.c_cflag &= ~CSTOPB;
    else if(stop_bits == 2)
        termios.c_cflag |= CSTOPB;
    else
        fprintf(stderr, "Invalid stop bit\n");

    int bits;

    switch(data_bits)
    {
        case 5:
        case 6:
        case 7:
        case 8:
            bits = dbits_map[data_bits];
            break;

        default:
            bits = -1;

    }

    if(bits != -1)
    {
        termios.c_cflag &= ~CSIZE;
        termios.c_cflag |= bits;
    } else
        fprintf(stderr, "Invalid data size\n");


    if(tcsetattr(fd, TCSANOW, &termios) == -1)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not get tty attributes from %s: %s\n", tty, strerror(errno));
        close(fd);
        return -1;
    }


    return fd;
}

/**
 * tty: "/dev/ttyUSB0"
 * baud: baudrate, for example 9600
 * mode: a string like 8N1 where 
 *       the first character is the number of data bits (range from 5-8)
 *       the second character is N (no parity), O (odd), E (even)
 *       the third character is the number of stop bits (1 or 2)
 */
int openSerial(const char *tty, int baud, const char *mode)
{
    if(tty == NULL || mode == NULL)
        return -1;

    if(strlen(mode) != 3)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "invalid mode\n");
        return -1;
    }

    int stop_bits = mode[2];
    if(stop_bits != '1' && stop_bits != '2')
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Invalid stop bits\n");
        return -1;
    }

    stop_bits -= '0';

    enum parity_t parity;
    switch(mode[1])
    {
        case 'n':
        case 'N':
            parity = PARITY_NO_PARITY;
            break;
        case 'o':
        case 'O':
            parity = PARITY_ODD;
            break;
        case 'e':
        case 'E':
            parity = PARITY_EVEN;
            break;
        default:
            fprintf(stderr, "Invalid parity\n");
            return -1;
    }

    int data_bits = mode[0] - '0';

    if(data_bits < 5 || data_bits > 8)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "invalid data bits\n");
        return -1;
    }

    return openSerial_long(tty, baud, parity, stop_bits, data_bits);
}
```

The most common mode is `"8N1"` (8 bit data, no parity, 1 stop bit) and I open
the serial line with

```
int fd = open("/dev/ttyUSB0", 9600, "8N1");

if(fd == -1)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Error, could not initialize serial line\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

I have no idea which serial settings you have to use, look it up in the manual.

Also be aware that stuff like this

```
n = write(fd, "AT I\r\n", 10);
```

is wrong, it's undefined behvaiour because `write` is reading beyon the bound
of the string literal. It would be better to do:

```
const char *cmd = "AT I\r\n";
n = write(fd, cmd, strlen(cmd));
```

then you would write the correct amount of data.

Like I said in the comments, I've made a google search on ISO 9141-2 and I could
not find any reliable information on whether it uses AT commands. So please
check the manual of the OBDII chip you are trying to read.

> *[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/On-board_diagnostics#OBD-II_signal_protocols)* says
>
> ISO 9141-2. This protocol has an asynchronous serial data rate of **10.4 kbit/s**. It is **somewhat similar to RS-232**; however, the signal levels are different, and communications happens on a single, bidirectional line without additional handshake signals. ISO 9141-2 is primarily used in Chrysler, European, and Asian vehicles.

It seems to me that this protocol is only similar to RS232, perhaps you need
another converter (other than [FT232R](http://www.ftdichip.com/Products/ICs/FT232R.htm)) which supports this baudrate.
[This](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/getting-started-with-obd-ii) page also states that the baudrate is 10400 bits/s, which is not
supported by default. I've found this [post](http://www.microchip.com/forums/m74601.aspx) which also suggests that you
should use two converters, one for the communication between OBD2 and converter
at 10.4 kbit/s and one between the converter and your PC at a standard baudrate
like 19.2 kbits/s.

Alternatively you could try to set a custom baudrate as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12646324/how-to-set-a-custom-baud-rate-on-linux) and
[here](https://gist.github.com/sentinelt/3f1a984533556cf890d9). I've never had to use custom baudrates, so I don't know if this
works.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so first off: I don't know C. However, you did n = (whatever to send the AT command) and for the read data you receive, then print. Why not attach the result of the read into a variable and print that? Or, you could use bash based commands to communicate with the serial port like "minicom" and I know there are others like that.

A couple other notes, as I have been working with OBD2 a lot lately: AT commands go to the reader, not the ECU. You can use minicom to see when you reset the adapter (ATZ) the ECU does nothing. However, send a 03 (or whatever mode is ECU CODE RESET) and it will clear your codes.
For more info on headers and things like that for multiple ECUs see https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/22982/received-frames-from-vehicles-with-multiple-ecu-chips

One last note: don't forget you have 2 different baud rates - one for your USB serial port to FT232R chip and one from said chip to the ECU. With ELM327 the latter is done via a AT command to change the proto. At any rate, use the FT232R baud rate coming from the computer, and test in minicom if necessary. Hope this helped!

Answer (score 0):

It's perfectly normal for an OBD2 adapter to send you back the very same command you have sent. This is called *echo mode* and can be turned off by sending `ATE0\r` as the first command. If you read more of the answer, you should see the result of your command coming after the echoed request.

Note also that the AT commands are processed by the OBD2 without sending data to any ECUs, only the PIDs (commands composed out of digits) will be sent over the bus.