# Setting Linux serial baud rate higher than 4 megabaud

Tags: linux, serial-port, raspberry-pi, raspbian, baud-rate

Super long story short: is it possible to read from a UART at something close to 12 megabaud?

I have a high speed connection that I am trying to read from on a Raspberry Pi. At present, the Raspberry Pi (and as far as I can tell, the world of serial programming) has a maximum baud rate of 4 Mbaud, which I achieved by setting the Raspberry Pi's UART clock to 160 MHz.

However, I need a UART running at 12+ Mbaud to capture the data streaming in from my external source. The Raspberry Pi's terminos.h file specifies 4 Mbaud as the max baud rate for serial communication. Is there a way to get higher baud rates? Is the key [ioctl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ioctl) from *[How can I set the baud rate to 307,200 on Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4968529/how-can-i-set-the-baud-rate-to-307-200-on-linux/7152671#7152671)*?

Raspbian 3.6.11, Raspberry Pi rev2

Answer (score 0):

Each UART has a hardware limit... If your hardware supports this rate, it's allowed... Verify it before.

Comment: [BCM2835 ARM datasheet](http://www.raspberrypi.org/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/BCM2835-ARM-Peripherals.pdf#page=11)
According to the datasheet, I should be able to get up to 15.62Mbaud, I think.